# spinner wont show up in the android program?

Tags: android, view, android-spinner

here are the codes

```
dChooser= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,R.array.d_choices);
dChooser.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and here is the xml part i dont understand what im doing wrong

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time2"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

Comment: just some advice : alignParentLeft is useless if you use layout_width="fill_parent". And instead of fill_parent you should use match_parent

Comment: well advice taken , thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Adapter seems wrong use something like this

```
dChooser= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.d_choices, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

dChooser.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: well it worked thanks , but adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  seems unnecessary

Comment: adapter.setDropDownViewResource() is used to set layout of the drop down list you can provide custom resources here if u want to maybe change colour or do other tweaks.